# How to get remote javascript file in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've read all topics I could find in stackoverflow and google, but still can't get this to work.

What I need - is to save my JS code in script on server, so I would not need to republish extension every time I decide to make changes. And users wouldn't have to upgrade their extensions also.

**Methods that do not work due to new Security Policy**:

- Inject script via adding  tag to
- Eval() script source after receiving it from ajax request.

As google says, **there is** some method to imlement remote script loading.

[Relaxing Security Policy for remote scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing)

Here is what they say:

> A relaxed policy definition which allows script resources to be loaded from example.com over HTTPS might look like:
>
> ```
> "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://example.com; object-src 'self'"
> ```

Ok, I did what they said in my manifest.json:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://beta.tradernet.ru; object-src 'self'"
```

And I try to load that script in my background.html

```
<head>
<title>My Awesome Backgound page!</title>
<script src="https://beta.tradernet.ru/js/extension-script.js"></script>
<script src="background.js"></script>
</head>
```

In my background.js I test if objects, declared in remote file are available. And **they are not available**....I'm not even sure that remote script was loaded...

If I add similar  tag to my popup.html, then it works and functions loaded from remote script **are** available...

**How do I make remote javascript functions available in background.js?**

Comment: Add your whole manifest please.

Answer (score 2):

I've got it working in my [workflowyCodeFormatter](https://github.com/ryanpcmcquen/workflowyCodeFormatter) extension. Your `manifest.json` is fine, what you need to do now is inject that script using JavaScript, something like this should do it:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  var scriptToLoad = document.createElement('script');
  scriptToLoad.type = 'text/javascript';
  scriptToLoad.async = true;
  scriptToLoad.src = 'https://beta.tradernet.ru/js/extension-script.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptToLoad, s);
}());
```

This allows me access to the JavaScript in my JS files, ironically though, the browser thinks I don't have them, even though executing everything works perfectly. To get around the browser spitting out console errors, I wrapped all my calls to the JS I needed in try/catch blocks. Let's say you wanted to call `fireWebSockets()` from your `extension-script.js`, you should do something like this:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    try {
      fireWebSockets(foo);
    } catch (ignore) {}
  });
}());
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Why the self-executing anonymous function pattern here?

Comment: To avoid global variables.

Comment: This is a bit old -- but do you know if it's possible to access `chrome` through a remotely loaded script?